# Eclipse/GCC Is there a DEBUG flag

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gcc

I am using Eclipse for several C++ projects.  I'd like to have some bits of purely debug code.  I expected this to work:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
   do_something();
#endif
```

but, alas, DEBUG is undefined.

Is there another #defined "word" that means DEBUG?  Or will I need to add a -DDEBUG to the compiler flags for the debug configuration.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard C mentions `NDEBUG` in the context of `<assert.h>`; when it is defined, `assert`s do nothing.

Otherwise there is no standard macro, and the safest path is to define something yourself.